# Reading from file with the stream extraction operator

Tags: c++, file-io, stream, operator-overloading

How can I make this bit of code read a file line by line?

inv.entry is a string that should read the entire line

```
istream& operator >>(istream& in, TODO& inv)
{ 
    ifstream in("TODO.txt");
    
    inv.incList();
    inv.currInvItem = inv.itemCount - 1;
    getline(in, inv.entry);
    
    return in;
}
```

I tried making it an ifstream but this does not work with the rest of my program. This code is accessed from

cin >> *this;

Comment: When overloading `operator>>` you should not create a new stream in it ... That kind of defeats the entire purpose of overloading `operator>>`. It should read from the given stream, which is the first parameter passed in.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work?